# $\iint_{D(0,1)}|f(x+iy)|^2 \, dx \, dy<\infty\implies$ removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D(0,2)\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. I have to prove that if 
$$\iint_{D(0,1)}|f(x+iy)|^2 \, dx \, dy<\infty,$$ then $0$ is a removable singularity.
My idea is that this integral is equal to the area of the image of $f$, but I couldn't think of anything else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: What happens when you take $f(z)=z^{-k}$ ($k\ge 1$) and compute $\iint_{D(0,1)} |f(z)|^2\,dx\,dy$? Then, in general, expand $f$ in Laurent series and think about what happens when you plug in a sum of terms or a whole Laurent series.